# Pandas conditional formula based on comparison of two cells

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

When calculating a new column called "duration_minutes", some of the results are negative because the values were put in the original columns backwards.

```
time.started_at=pd.to_datetime(time.started_at)
time.ended_at=pd.to_datetime(time.ended_at)
time["duration_minutes"]=(time.ended_at-time.started_at).dt.total_seconds()/60
time.head()
```

A quick check for negatives `time[time.duration_minutes<0]` in the "duration_minutes" column shows many rows with negative values because the start and stop times are in the wrong columns.

Is there a way to create and calculate the "duration_minutes" column to deal with this situation?

Comment: Take the absolute value with [abs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html)? `(time.ended_at-time.started_at).abs().dt.total_seconds()/60`

Comment: Agree. Just use abs to get the absolute value.  Question is you just want the duration ? What about the start/end time, they are in the wrong column.  Won't it be better if you check upstream why the values are wrongly placed ?   Once you solve your upstream issue, you can then check the duration if -ve, then you know something is wrong prior to this step.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. This is one of the recommendations I am making - Ensure times are accurately recorded.